# Simple Transistor Circuit Question

Tags: arduino, transistors, motor

I know this question title is not the best, but it describes the question well.
I am confused with one thing. Why does this circuit work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ06LR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By work I mean turn the 12V relay on. And this doesn't.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2z3wV.png)</sup>

I have tested it out on a breadboard. The first one is able to run the Relay and the second one can't.

Why is that so? What difference does it make if the load is before or after the transistor.

PS: I am using BD435 transistor. And a motor instead of relay.

Comment: Your top circuit will work once when you switch it on and then kill the BJT when you switch it off. Add a reverse connected diode across the coil (in both circuits) to prevent damage by back emf.

Comment: @JImDearden yup i know that. But for the simplicity I didnt add it. Thanks for pointing it out though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd circuit doesn't work because to turn on the transistor you need a base emitter voltage of 0.7 volts and that means, at best the emitter is at about 4.3 volts and that would be the voltage on the relay.

Think about the first circuit and why it works - it's easy to forward bias the base emitter junction because the emitter is at ground. With the emitter connected to the relay, the moment you apply the base voltage the emitter must rise with that base voltage but be 0.7 volts lower. This only partially turns on the transistor.

Or if you expected the emitter to be 12 volts in the 2nd example then the base would need to be 12.7 volts.

The bottom line is that the forward biased base emitter junction IS a diode and behaves like one.

Comment: So when the emitter is connected to ground, the base-emitter voltage requirement is 0.7 volts and the transistor fully turns on?

Comment: Correct, and when the emitter is not tethered to 0V it will only ever be about 0.7 volts below the base (for an NPN transistor) irrespective of the load on the emitter (within reason of course). This is why this type of circuit is called and "emitter follower" - the emitter follows the base's undulations up and down or steady state with a fairly constant 0.5 to 1 volt difference (for extremes of reasonable situations). It's why they say the gain of an emitter follower is approximately unity - it's because it follows the base.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. TBH i always make the second circuit then after trying it out I remember this never works. So I though I should get detail on why it doesn't work.